# How to Update JSF datatable using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I m dynamically adding input text using datatable by pressing command button,but each time row is added page gets refreshed how i can add a row in datatable without refreshing the page using ajax. Here is the code

```
<h:form>

    <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{dataTableBean.cities}" var="city">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="City name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{city}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton value="Add one more city" id="ajax" update="table"
        actionListener="#{dataTableBean.enlargeList}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{dataTableBean.processList}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: You are confusing Primefaces UI components (**p**) and standard JSF components (**h**). Check out documentation of both command buttons, spot the difference, and get back if you have further questions.

Comment: Also, be sure to *understand* the difference between **action** and **action listener**, as described, for example, in this excellent answer: [Differences between action and actionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382).

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is supposed to be a *working excercise*, posting anything close to an answer will damage the OP's understanding of the subject.

So, I will give some *hints* so that OP could solve the problem on his own.

1. You are confusing **Primefaces** UI components, whose tags start with `<p:...>` and standard **JSF** UI components `<h:...>`. Regarding your example, there is [`<h:commandButton>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) and [`<p:commandButton>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/commandButton.html). As far as Primefaces components were designed to provide user with a more convenient interface, there are **some additional attributes** in the Primefaces counterpart to the standard command button. Spot them and pay attention to the AJAX specification. Take a closer look at `ajax` and `update` attributes.
2. [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag enables ajax behaviour for `UIComponent`s implementing the `ClientBehaviorHolder` interface. Similarly, [`<p:ajax>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/ajax.html) tag does basically the same with some enhancements and is used by Primefaces components. These tags can be bested, for example, within `<h:commandButton>`/`<p:commandButton>` and specify ajax behaviour of that component. Pay attention to `execute`/`render` attributes of `<f:ajax>` and/or `process`/`update` attributes of `<p:ajax>`. This way the command button wouldn't fire a standard form submit, but will trigger an AJAX call.
3. Be sure to understand the difference between **action** and **action listener** of command buttons. The latter is designed to execute some *minor adjustments* (logging/accessing attributes of caller/tuning some properties, etc.), while the former is used to execute a *business action* (save/delete/update, etc.). Excellent start is reading  [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382).

In the end, be sure **not to confuse input and output components** within your code.

Finally, consulting a good source of information is a very good idea. You can start with official documentation ([Primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html), [Oracle's tutorial on Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)) and then carry on with ***reliable sources of information***. My personal preferences go to the following (brilliant) sources: [BalusC tutorials on Java EE in general and JSF in particular](http://balusc.blogspot.com/), [Marty Hall's tutorials on a wide spectrum of subjects within Java](http://coreservlets.com/) and [Mkyong's tutorials, covering concrete problems within Java EE](http://www.mkyong.com/), in case you want a concrete example.